Request mapping on class and method both creating issue on returning view name from controller
i am working on spring mvc where i put mapping on controller class and also on method see the code below:
controller code:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/role")
public class RoleController {

    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

    @GetMapping("/roles")
    public String roles(@ModelAttribute Role role, Model model, RedirectView view) {
        
            System.out.println("update e "+model.getAttribute("hasError"));     
//          System.out.println("role edxists = "+model.getAttribute("role"));
            if(model.getAttribute("hasError")==null) {
                model.addAttribute("hasError",false);
            }
        
            model.addAttribute("roles",roleService.getAllRoles());
        
        if(model.getAttribute("update")!=null && (boolean)model.getAttribute("update")) {
            model.addAttribute("update",false);
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("role",new Role());
        }
        
        
        
        return "role-overview";
    }
}

i am hitting the url role/roles from home.jsp by clicking a button cole below:
<a href="role/roles" class="text-light" ><div style="height:50px;font-size:30px;" class="container mb-1 col-4 bg-info text-center ">
    <p>Role Overview</p>
</div></a>

view resolver code:

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver vr=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        vr.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
        vr.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return vr;
    }
    

when the controller runs and returns the view name i got this error below:
Type Status Report
Message JSP file [/role/WEB-INF/view/role-overview.jsp] not found
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
enter image description here
i understood the problem that when the controller return the view name it concatenate WEB-INF/view/role-overview with controller mapping url role which in result role/WEB-INF/view/role-overview. how can i resolve this issue ?
i just use GetMapping annotation on controller method before this i am using request mapping only

Use absolute path instead.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
